# Is there a way to programmatically perform input action on system permission dialogs on Android?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-mediaprojection

***This request is for a specific use case of a product***

Assuming I have an AccessibilityService instantiated as part of my application's context: I need to continuously capture screen content, for which i'm using a MediaProjectionManager attached to my application. This is working, with a caveat: every time I restart my device or app, is mandatory to make a new request for an instance of MediaProjection, forcing the user to accept the screen capture system permission dialog.

I am trying to skip this step for the user. I already achieved automatically firing the dialog request. But for accepting the dialog prompt, this is what I've tried:

1. Log view hierarchy and find the nodeViewId of the corresponding
   dialog accept button. Problem: the AccessibilityService wasn't providing an
   event.source for that system dialog.
2. Using AccessibilityService.dispatchGesture to perform a click action
   on the coordinate of the "Start Now" button of the dialog, after the
   system shows it.

```
       // PermissionAutomator
       permissionsAutomator.listener = object : PermissionsAutomator.Listener {
           override fun onPerformClickOnCoordinate() {
               val clickPath = Path()
               clickPath.moveTo(604F, 737F)
               val clickStroke = StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, 1)
               val clickBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()
               clickBuilder.addStroke(clickStroke)
               val gesture =  clickBuilder.build()
               val callback = object : GestureResultCallback() {
                   override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription) {
                       super.onCompleted(gestureDescription)
                       Timber.d("gesture onCompleted")
                   }

                   override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription) {
                       super.onCancelled(gestureDescription)
                       Timber.d("gesture onCancelled")
                   }
               }
               dispatchGesture(gesture, callback, null)
           }
       }
```

Does anyone has some advice for this problem? Maybe the solution can be extended for every system permission dialog on Android. Thanks!

[System permission dialog for MediaProjection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20ujO.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want to skip the screen capture permission dialouge?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `MediaProjectionManager` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager
it seems its built-in to ask every time. Its not a regular permission like `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` that is saved. The only way I see around it is to make your own and since `MediaProjectionManager` and `MediaProjection` are `final` it would have to be from scratch if its even possible.

Comment: As it's not a regular permission and the system asks for it every time, I'm trying to find a way to "skip" the process of manually giving the permission every time the user restarts the app or device.

Comment: I get that but `MediaProjectionManager` wont provide you a `MediaProjection` otherwise as its apart of the process. You could use `Reflection` or some bytecode manipulation library to bi-pass the `finality ` of  `MediaProjectionManager` and subvert the request so it never shows and you can call `getMediaProjection` regardless of the permission.